# How to combine multiple CSV files into one Big CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a zip file that contains over 70 csv files. I want to combine the information in all these files into one big csv file. Using the append method in python will take a long time because I will have to load all the files one after the other and then use append for each file. Is there any other way I can achieve this with python without appending each file one after the other?

I have tried using append in python to combine the info in the files but it is taking a lot of time because I have to load over 70 the files first and then append one after the other.

I am hoping to reduce the time spent by just loading the files once and then use python to loop through each file and combine the information in each csv file into one big csv file. Is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Do the CSV files fit to memory at the same time? What is the total uncompressed byte size?

Comment: Do the CSV files have the exact same header (first line)?

Comment: Please add your existing solution to the question, to clarify what exactly is too slow.

Comment: If the first lines of all CSV files are identical, there is a simple, fast solution, memory-efficient: print that first line, print each CSV file without their first line.

Comment: I have rolled back your recent edits. Please don't change the scope of your question after you have received an answer. Merging Excel files into a single CSV files is a whole different thing than merging CSV files that you originally asked about (and received an answer _and_ a duplicate for). Also, IMHO asking how to merge multiple Excel files into a single CSV is IMHO to broad. as it is basically asking two to three different things (reading Excel files, writing CSV, and maybe how to read multiple files while using a single output). In any case, you'll need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The CONCAT function can be used to resolve this.

first

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import os

# Path to the zip file and
zip_file_path = 'path/to/your/zipfile.zip'
# Path to the directory you want to save the file
extraction_directory = 'path/to/extraction/directory'

# Extract the zip file
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(extraction_directory)

# Loops ,reads the CSV file and append it
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(extraction_directory) if f.endswith('.csv')]
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(extraction_directory, f)) for f in csv_files]

combined_csv = pd.concat(dataframe, ignore_index=True)

# Save the combined df to a new csv file
combined_csv.to_csv('path/to/combined_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: The global variable `df` is never set. Are you sure your code works? Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you. But I think there is an error in line 18 of your code, but I changed the 'df' to 'dataframes' and it worked, just in case you want to edit your answer. Thank you very much, your answer was really helpful.

Comment: yes , i have editted it now